# Faster alternatives for "IN" statements?

Tags: mysql

I'm not great with MySQL, so I often find myself preparing sub-optimal queries that work, but I know must be horribly inefficient. I'm hoping you guys could give me some pointers on why the following query doesn't work well, and what methods I should use to accomplish similar queries.

I have the following table structure:

```
TABLE Files
files_id => INT(12), PRIMARY, AUTO INCREMENT, NOT NULL
files_name => VARCHAR(255), NOT NULL
(some other fields such as file type etc)

TABLE File_Permissions
perm_id => INT(12), PRIMARY, AUTO INCREMENT, NOT NULL
perm_files_id => INT(12), NOT NULL
perm_users_id => INT(12), NOT NULL
```

I pull a list of the files a user is allowed to view with the following SQL:

```
SELECT files_name FROM Files WHERE files_id IN 
    (SELECT perm_files_id FROM File_Permissions WHERE perm_users_id = 'xxxxxx');
```

This, as far as I can tell, will go through each of the thousands of records in the Files table, and for each one execute a subquery that selects from the File_Permissions table to check against the user's ID.

**This takes almost 2 seconds per query.** I'm sure something is fundamentally wrong with this, I just don't know what it is.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You should add info on existing (if any) indexes

Comment: There were no existing indexes, anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most queries that involve an IN clause for a subquery can be refactored to use a join. In your case:

```
SELECT files_name 
FROM Files 
JOIN File_Permissions ON files_id = perm_files_id
WHERE perm_users_id = 'xxxxxx';
```

The above query will create a result set of the join between the two tables, then filter by the conditions. This requires two passes instead of N+1.

Comment: This might duplicate the file names.

Comment: Thanks for this, it clearly makes the query faster 100-fold (1.5s -> .015s) to use a `JOIN` rather than `IN`. This was something I did not know. Cheers!

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos - Valid point; if there are multiple permissions in File_Permissions that apply to each file, this join will create duplicate entries, one for each permission granted to the same file. You can use SELECT DISTINCT to return only one row per file in this particular query; however if you start including information from File_Permissions in the column list, the duplicate file names will come back because each row's data, as a unit, will be unique.

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of query you can use a JOIN, WHERE ... IN, or WHERE EXISTS. An approach using IN like you have posted should be fine assuming you have the appropriate indexes.

Just so you can compare with something else, here's an example of the WHERE EXISTS:

```
SELECT files_name FROM Files
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM File_Permissions
    WHERE perm_users_id = 'xxxxxx'
    AND files_id = perm_files_id
)
```

But most important thing is: **add the appropriate indexes**! This can make a *huge* difference to the performance. If you are unsure if you have the correct indexes please look at the output of the following statements to see which indexes you have and which indexes the query is using:

- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...your query here...`
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE Files`
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE File_Permissions`

If you still are't sure, edit the question to include the output of each of the above statements and also these:

- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Files`
- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM File_Permissions`
- `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ...your query here...) T1`

Comment: +1 and thank you for the info on Indexes, after adding the proper indexes, my previous query using IN went from 1.5s to .09s (15x Faster!)

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your query as above, but you may also try putting an index on perm_users_id first.  It will probably speed things up quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables need indexes.  The query above shows me you need the following:

Table `Files` needs and index on `files_id`

Table `File_Permissions` needs and index on `perm_users_id`

That will make the query a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not sure why you're not just using a standard join as follows:</strike>

```
SELECT <required fields> FROM (Files, File_Permissions) WHERE
files_id = perm_files_id AND perm_user_id='xxxxx'
```

Beyond that, you should ensure that the appropriate indexes are set, etc.

Implicit joins are evil - see comments below. :-)

Comment: No. Bad coder. This is the old style of joining; it is inefficient and should not be used in any SQL RDBMS that supports the new JOIN syntax, and certainly not in an answer meant to educate.

Comment: @KeithS I've obliterated my wrongness. Must confess I didn't realise implicit joins were deemed evil these days, if that's the issue. (I presumed this syntax is just converted to a "normal" left join by the SQL interpreter.) Feel free to enlighten me and I'll then delete this answer.

Comment: There may not be a significant difference in performance in this particular case; SQL Server, for one, would generate the same execution plan for something simple like this. However the "ANSI Join" syntax is easier to understand and harder to screw up once you've learned it, and for those reasons alone it is recommended over the old-style join by virtually every SQL book and blog I can get my hands on.

Comment: Also, when the OP moves over from MySQL to MS SQL Server or Oracle, he'll find that the latest versions of both no longer support the old join syntax.

Comment: @KeithS Thanks for the info. To be honest, I'll leave this question intact as the advice you've offered justifies its presence I'd say. Just hope no-one else downvotes it. :-)

Comment: wow, i also felt implicit join was easier... but thanks for keeping the answer around for preserving comments' advice.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT files_name FROM Files LEFT JOIN File_permissions ON files_id = perm_files_id 
AND perm_users_id = 'xxxxx'
```

also indexing the joined columns will help performance. So an Index on perm_files_id would increase performance

Answer (score 0):

Two common alternatives are:

```
SELECT files_name
  FROM Files f
  WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM File_Permissions
         WHERE f.files_id = perm_files_id
           AND perm_users_id = 'xxxxxx');
```

and:

```
SELECT DISTINCT files_name fn
  FROM Files f
  JOIN File_Permissions fp ON f.files_id = fp.perm_files_id
 WHERE perm_users_id = 'xxxxxx';
```